# Excel VBA - Filter in worksheets that are labeled 3 characters length

Tags: excel, vba

Please assist in writing the vba code for an array where in the workbook, worksheets that are 3 character length to run this command:

For example, if the worksheets are labeled: ATE, ARE, FOR, ETC, then it'll be filtered. If the worksheets are labeled more than or less than 3 letters then ignore. Hope this clear things up. Thanks.

Error received from code below:

> Compile error: invalid qualifier.

```
Dim N As Long Dim wsName As String

 For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
     wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name

     If Len(wsName) = 3 Then

     wsName.Range("$A$1:$XFC$104").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=365" _
         , Operator:=xlAnd
     wsName.Range("$A$1:$XFC$104").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">100" _
         , Operator:=xlAnd

     Else 'Do Nothing
     End If 
 Next N
```

Comment: Can you clarify this 'folders that are labeled 3 letters' portion, I really am not understanding it.

Comment: I meant 3 character length. For example, if the worksheets are labeled: ATE, ARE, FOR, ETC, then it'll be filtered. If the worksheets are labeled more than or less than 3 letters then ignore. Hope this clear things up. Thanks.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" stand for exactly? Getting any error? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Compile error: invalid qualifier.

Comment: When the IDE highlighted the invalid qualifier after clicking "Debug", what was highlighted?

Comment: WsNAME is highlighted. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're making references incorrectly.

wsName = string.  That means you're copying the name of the sheet only.

The reference you're making is "Sheet1".Range().action

That's not appropriate syntax.  This would be appropriate:

```
Sheets(wsName).Range().Action
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cyril.

Here's the working code:

```
    Dim N As Long
    Dim wsName As String
    For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name
    If Len(wsName) = 3 Then

    Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$1104").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=365" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$1104").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">100" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If
Next N
```